# Get difference in Minutes for DateTime format column

Tags: 2013, list, calculated-column, date-time

I have a formula for calculated column which gets the date difference in hh:mm format.

```
=TEXT([COLUMN2]-[COLUMN1],"h:mm")
```

But I want to get the difference in just minutes. I created very complex formula and they didn't work. For example:

```
=TEXT((TEXT(([COLUMN2]-[COLUMN1]),"h")*60)+(([COLUMN2]-(TEXT(([COLUMN2]-[COLUMN1]),"h")*60))-[COLUMN1]))
```

Please help me about getting the difference in minutes.

The result that I expect:

> 1/15/2014 16:35 1/15/2014 16:45 The result should be 10.
>
> 1/15/2014 7:00  1/15/2014 7:00  The result should be 0.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? I updated my answer to show that it works exactly as you expect

Comment: Ow I'm so stupid. I forgot to change the return type as number from date time format. It didn't work with the 1440. but what I wrote is worked. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm totally stumped. Anyhow, good that it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-HP010070468.aspx#BMtime_unit) it should be easy.

Try this:

```
=([COLUMN2] - [COLUMN1])*1440
```

This will return the total number of minutes between the two dates

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: It looks like it should work correct. But gives me this kind of results 12/20/1899 0:00.

Comment: What data type did you set for the calculated field? It must be a number not a date

Comment: It's date. Not number. 1/15/2014 21:30. So what should I do?

Comment: The formula returns a number. The data type for the calculated column must be a number. How could a number representing a time span in minutes be converted to a date?

Comment: Im trying to converting the date into number. Not the reverse. If I can get the h:mm so there should be a way too.

Comment: sorry, I don't follow you. Please update your question with an example of the result you expect to see

Comment: I add to my question. I tried this too but it didn't work. =HOUR(COLUMN2-COLUMN1)*60+MINUTE(COLUMN2-COLUMN1)

Comment: i get you! so you have the hours and mins but instead you just want to show it as mins? so if it was 1 hour and 10 min you want to show 70 min?

Comment: @aliSharepoint my formula does exactly this!

Comment: I forgot to mark it as answer. Your formula worked. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following formula in the calculated column,

```
=MINUTE([Column2]-[Column1])
```

the above code returns Minutes between two times.

for more information, please refer the following link,

[Calculated Field Formulas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: It always gives 5 or for the 0 difference 12/30/1899 0:00 or 1/9/1900 0:00.

Comment: this formula returns the difference in the minutes unit between two times, not the total number of minutes between the two dates

Comment: Sorry for the uncleared explaination. Yes I want the total number of minutes of the difference.

Comment: @e.ozmen see my answer then

Answer (score 0):

```
=[COLUMN1]+([COLUMN2]/1440)
```

i think the key here is to get the full ammount of minutes in a day, col 1 is the start date and col 2 end date

**EDIT**

this should work!

```
=INT(([Column2]-[Column1])*1440)
```

above was taken from link below but converted to work in sharepoint!

> 06/09/2007 10:35 AM **vs** 06/10/2007 3:30 PM
>
> =INT((Column2-Column1)*1440)
>
> Total minutes between two times (1735)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-sharepoint-services-help/examples-of-common-formulas-HA001160947.aspx

Comment: But how can this get the difference ?

Comment: just updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Hours Calculation:

```
=([COLUMN2] - [COLUMN1])*24
```

This will return the total number of hours between the dates