# Calculated column to show differece between start time and end time

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, date-time

I have two date columns in a custom list: **Start time** and **End time**, both are set to today's date and just select the time.

Now I want to add a new column that will automatically show the subtraction of End time from Start time.

How can this be done?

Comment: Start with how you do it in Excel, most basic calculations are the same in SP

Comment: Shout out to @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, this is a great resource:  http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
=INT(([End Date]-[Start Date])*1440)
```

[image]

Answer here also: 
[Get difference in Minutes for DateTime format column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87907/get-difference-in-minutes-for-datetime-format-column)